# vba - adding text to a bookmark - Runtimeerror 428

Tags: vba, ms-word

```
Dim AppWD As Object
Dim objDoc As Object
Dim objDocProdTP As Object
...
Set AppWD = CreateObject("Word.Application") 'Word als Object starten
AppWD.Visible = True
Set objDocProdTP = AppWD.documents.Open(workPath & "\vorlagen\LFPostTemplate.docx")
Set objDoc = AppWD.documents.Open(workPath & "\vorlagen\LFTemplate2.docx")
...
MsgBox (objDocProdTP.Bookmarks.Count)
...
objDocProdTP.Goto what:=-1, Name:="lblPos"
objDocProdTP.TypeText (wbQuelle.Sheets("Tabelle1").Cells(i, 7))
```

`MsgBox (objDocProdTP.Bookmarks.Count)` returns 19 which is the total number of Bookmarks in LFPostTemplate.docx.
But `objDocProdTP.TypeText (wbQuelle.Sheets("Tabelle1").Cells(i, 7))` returns Runtimeerror 428 "method or property not supported by this Object" (i get my errors in German so its freely translated)

What I want to do is to replace text marked as a bookmark

The other point is that i want to append text to a text already in a bookmark

Answer (score 0):

`TypeText` is a method of `Selection`, not of a Document. You will find it helpful to test expressions in the Word VBA Editor, and click in the word (a method or property, etc.) and press F1 to get into the Help system.

You can set, and retrieve, the text at a Bookmark more easily, and more efficiently, with:

```
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("bkTest").Range.Text = "Hello"

objDocProdTP.Bookmarks("lblPos").Range.Text = "Hello"

objDocProdTP.Bookmarks("lblPos").Range.Text = _ 
    objDocProdTP.Bookmarks("lblPos").Range.Text & " hello"
```

Comment: objDocProdTP.Bookmarks("lblPos").Range.Text = "Hello" produces Runtime error 5941 requested element is not in collection